# TFTP on ARv7 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, networking, router, client, tftp

The only machine I have with an ethernet port is my Odroid C1 (Raspberry Pi Equivalent). It has an ARMv7 processor. I'm currently halfway through flashing an old linksys router to the DD-WRT firmware, and I need a way to PUT a file with this machine which is running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have been unable to find a TFTP client which supports my architecture. Does anyone know of such a program? If so, as I am not able to connect to the internet on that machine at the moment, could someone direct me to the package download?

Comment: You can download it directly from the repositories: [tftp](http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/n/netkit-tftp/tftpd_0.17-18ubuntu2_armhf.deb).

Comment: Sure, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the armhf .deb package for tftp is in the repositories:

[tftpd_0.17-18ubuntu2_armhf.deb](http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/universe/n/netkit-tftp/tftpd_0.17-18ubuntu2_armhf.deb)